# PHP Change Array Order for Parent-Child Relation

Tags: php, arrays

**Current Array Structure:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

            [TASK_ID] => 2
            [PARENT_TASKID] => 0
            [TASK_LEVEL] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [TASK_ID] => 1
            [PARENT_TASKID] => 0
            [TASK_LEVEL] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [TASK_ID] => 4
            [PARENT_TASKID] => 1
            [TASK_LEVEL] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [TASK_ID] => 5
            [PARENT_TASKID] => 1
            [TASK_LEVEL] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [TASK_ID] => 6
            [PARENT_TASKID] => 5
            [TASK_LEVEL] => 2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [TASK_ID] => 9
            [PARENT_TASKID] => 2
            [TASK_LEVEL] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [TASK_ID] => 10
            [PARENT_TASKID] => 2
            [TASK_LEVEL] => 1
        )
)
```

You can observe that `PARENT_TASKID` is `TASK_ID` for childs. For example:

```
Array
        (
            [TASK_ID] => 9
            [PARENT_TASKID] => 2
        )
```

Here `TASK_ID = 9` is the child of `TASK_ID = 2`. Note the `PARENT_TASKID`.

```
Array (
            [TASK_ID] => 2
            [PARENT_TASKID] => 0
            [TASK_LEVEL] => 0
        )
```

How can I change the above array format so the the child array comes under its parent and looks like below:

```
[0] => Array
    (

        [TASK_ID] => 2
        [PARENT_TASKID] => 0
        [TASK_LEVEL] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [TASK_ID] => 9
        [PARENT_TASKID] => 2
        [TASK_LEVEL] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [TASK_ID] => 10
        [PARENT_TASKID] => 2
        [TASK_LEVEL] => 1
    )
```

I do not what to place the children exactly beneath parents but change the array order accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a topological sort. You can find some information on how to approach this here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting